# AWS S3 resolves randomly with ip not responding on 443

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

Since 1 week, i've flaky tests with ETIMEOUT from aws-sdk  (v2 nodejs), on region us-west-2.
It's with S3 API, and it resolve ips that havn't port 443 opened, seems to behave like a drop rule.

For instance:

> connect ETIMEDOUT 3.5.80.126:443

I have check the dns of my company, and i've force the dns to 8.8.8.8 without more success.

EDIT: this ip does not answer from my company or from my home (France/Europe), but answers from an aws instance.

Comment: Why do you think DNS has anything to do with this? You seem to be resolving the us-west-2 S3 endpoint just fine (you have an IP address).

Comment: Is the same S3 endpoint name resolving to different IPs on the good vs. bad systems? What are they?

Comment: @jarmod: yes, sometime it resolves with an unreachable ip (ex: 3.5.80.192), most of the time the ip works (ex 52.92.176.224)

Comment: If you have AWS support, you might consider raising a support case. Ask if both IPs are valid S3 IPs. Ask support to explain the difference and why one might not work as reliably as the other. The 3.5.80.126 IP reverses to s3-us-west-2-r-w.amazonaws.com which seems to be valid.